# Executing Stored Proc in Pervasive Control Center

Tags: sql, pervasive-sql

I am relatively new to Pervasive Control Center and I was wondering if I wanted to test a stored Procedure to see its results, how would I simply select that stored proc? I have:

```
Select SP_test_getMeasure06
```

I am sure I am missing something because I know this is legal my syntax must be off slightly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a stored procedure using either `Call` or `Exec`.  For example:

```
exec SP_test_getMeasure06
```

You'll need to make sure your stored procedure uses the `RETURNS` clause to get data back.  For more information check out the [Stored Procedure](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=ODBC/syntaxref.03.23.html) docs.